# Count records per month with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table, let's call them `SUMMARYDATA`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT       STATUSIN           STATUSOUT               LATECOME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         00:06:23             
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:00:00               
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-23 08:30:00  2020-01-23 11:00:00         00:30:00
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         00:05:00
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-21 07:06:20  2020-01-21 13:58:31         00:00:00             
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:00:00               
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-23 07:06:00  2020-01-23 10:30:00         00:00:00
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-24 09:06:00  2020-01-23 10:30:00         02:06:00
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-21 07:06:23  2020-01-21 11:55:30         00:00:00             
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:00:44         00:00:00               
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-23 08:37:00  2020-01-23 11:13:00         00:37:00
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-24 08:09:00  2020-01-24 10:22:00         00:09:00
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-21 07:06:20  2020-01-21 13:58:31         00:00:00             
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:00:00               
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-23 06:06:00  2020-01-23 11:30:00         00:00:00
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-24 09:06:00  2020-01-23 15:30:00         02:06:00
A5   BRIAN   BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         00:06:23             
A5   BRIAN   BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:00:00               
A5   BRIAN   BB         2020-01-23 08:30:00  2020-01-23 11:00:00         00:30:00
A5   BRIAN   BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         00:05:00
```

I need to `SELECT(DEPARTMENT,MONTH,YEARS,COUNT(LATECOME))` and `COUNT` the records `Count (where LATECOME > '00:00:01') > 2` in per month.

Because, Aria & Brian has `LATECOME > 2` in per month, Belle & Ziya only 1 `LATECOME`, and Chloe Only 2 `LATECOME` in per month. So, in Department BB just 1 that is Aria, and Department CC is 0, because Chloe & Ziya `<= 2 LATECOME`.

And this is the sample output that I mean:

```
DEPARTMENT     MONTH    YEAR       LATECOME
-------------------------------------------
  BB            01      2020           2              
  CC            01      2020           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [NAME], DEPARTMENT, MONTH(STATUSIN) [MONTH], YEAR(STATUSIN) [YEAR], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN LATECOME = '00:00:00' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY [NAME], DEPARTMENT, MONTH(STATUSIN), YEAR(STATUSIN) ORDER BY [NAME]) Total
    FROM SUMMARYDATA
)

SELECT DEPARTMENT, [MONTH], [YEAR], SUM(CASE WHEN TOTAL > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) LATECOME
FROM cte
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT, [MONTH], [YEAR]
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6c6a95d5c2b23406fe6c1535009cdef0)**.

Comment: sacse's way is way better than mine :)  - I'm old school :(

Comment: @Srinika every answer with the correct output is gr8 \m/ :).

Comment: yours is more concise

Comment: thank you so much for helping me:) it's work.. but when i running with my real data.. i have 2 people in Department BB that have `LATECOME > 2`.. why the output only show 1 not 2? @sacse

Comment: please check my updated question to see the sample data and the output.. thankss:)  @sacse

Answer (score 2):

```
Create table #SUMMARYDATA(NIP varchar(10), NAME varchar(50),DEPARTMENT varchar(90),STATUSIN datetime, STATUSOUT datetime,LATECOME TIME(0))
Insert into #SUMMARYDATA
Values('A1','ARIA','BB','2020-01-21 08:06:23','2020-01-21 11:58:36','00:06:23'),             
('A1','ARIA','BB','2020-01-22 07:34:27','2020-01-22 17:19:47','00:00:00'),               
('A1','ARIA','BB','2020-01-23 08:30:00','2020-01-23 11:00:00','00:30:00'),
('A1','ARIA','BB','2020-01-24 08:05:00','2020-01-24 10:30:00','00:05:00'),
('A2','BELLE','BB','2020-01-21 07:06:20','2020-01-21 13:58:31','00:00:00'),            
('A2','BELLE','BB','2020-01-22 07:34:27','2020-01-22 17:19:47','00:00:00'),               
('A2','BELLE','BB','2020-01-23 07:06:00','2020-01-23 10:30:00','00:00:00'),
('A2','BELLE','BB','2020-01-24 09:06:00','2020-01-23 10:30:00','02:06:00'),
('A3','CHLOE','CC','2020-01-21 07:06:23','2020-01-21 11:55:30','00:00:00'),             
('A3','CHLOE','CC','2020-01-22 07:34:27','2020-01-22 17:00:44','00:00:00'),               
('A3','CHLOE','CC','2020-01-23 08:37:00','2020-01-23 11:13:00','00:37:00'),
('A3','CHLOE','CC','2020-01-24 08:09:00','2020-01-24 10:22:00','00:09:00'),
('A4','ZIYA','CC','2020-01-21 07:06:20','2020-01-21 13:58:31','00:00:00'),             
('A4','ZIYA','CC','2020-01-22 07:34:27','2020-01-22 17:19:47','00:00:00'),               
('A4','ZIYA','CC','2020-01-23 06:06:00','2020-01-23 11:30:00','00:00:00'),
('A4','ZIYA','CC','2020-01-24 09:06:00','2020-01-23 15:30:00','02:06:00')


Select s.DEPARTMENT,Q.[Month],Q.[Year], 
    Case when Max(LateCount) > 2 then 1 Else 0 End as LateCome  
from #SUMMARYDATA s 
inner join 
(
 SELECT NAME, MONTH(StatusIn) as [Month] , YEAR(StatusIn) as [Year], 
 Sum(Case when LateCome > '00:00:00' then 1 Else 0 End) as LateCount 
 from #SUMMARYDATA
 group by NAME,  MONTH(StatusIn), YEAR(StatusIn)
) Q 
ON MONTH(s.StatusIn) = Q.[Month] and YEAR(s.StatusIn) =Q.[Year] and s.NAME = q.NAME
group by  s.DEPARTMENT,Q.[Month],Q.[Year]
```

--- Or make it a bit more elegant

```
;With sdCTE as
(
 SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT, MONTH(StatusIn) as [Month] , YEAR(StatusIn) as [Year],  
 Case when LateCome > '00:00:00' then 1 Else 0 End as LateCome 
 from #SUMMARYDATA
)
Select DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year], 
    Case when Max(LateCount) > 2 then 1 Else 0 End as LateCome  
from
(
    select Name, DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year], Sum(LateCome) LateCount  
    from sdCTE
    group by Name,DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year]
) Q
Group by DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year]
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me:) it's work.. but when i running with my real data.. i have 2 people in Department BB that have `LATECOME` > 2.. why the output only show 1 not 2?

Comment: please check my updated question to see the sample data and the output.. thankss:)

Comment: That I did, with the assumption, you need 1 or 0 if late attendance condition met. Please check my new solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is for the changed requirements

```
;With sdCTE as
(
 SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT, MONTH(StatusIn) as [Month] , YEAR(StatusIn) as [Year],  
 Case when LateCome > '00:00:00' then 1 Else 0 End as LateCome 
 from #SUMMARYDATA
)

Select DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year], 
    Sum(Case when (LateCount) > 2 then 1 Else 0 End) as LateCome  
from
(
    select Name, DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year], Sum(LateCome) LateCount  
    from sdCTE
    group by Name,DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year]
) Q
Group by DEPARTMENT, [Month],[Year]
```